# Como interpretar esta linha? (struct lista*)0)

Tags: c, struct, cast

```
while (variavel != (struct lista*)0) {
   ...
}
```

Como interpretar `(struct lista*)0)`? O que quer dizer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(struct lista*)` é um *cast*, então o código está dizendo para o compilador interpretar o valor a seguir como sendo deste tipo especificado, ou seja, um ponteiro para uma estrutura chamada `lista` declarada previamente. Neste caso é só uma forma de deixar claro que você sabe que o está fazendo e que é isto mesmo que quer, ou seja, a variável `variavel` deve ser exatamente do tipo `struct lista *`, já que `0` originalmente é um tipo `int`, com o *cast* fica garantido que é compatível do ponto de vista de tipo. Mas claro, nada garante que o dado seja o que é esperado ali. O `0` neste caso é um indicativo de ponteiro nulo, então o laço parará quando o valor de `variavel` for nulo.

Comment: Como o cast ficaria sem o ponteiro? Exemplo: struct lista variavel. Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.

Comment: Simples assim é só tirar o ponteiro, mas não quer dizer que funcionará em todos os casos.